# I got Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql

[table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XszuP.png)   UPDATE adhoc_answer_crpinspection_archive 
        SET answer='YES'
    WHERE (
            SELECT * 
            FROM adhoc_answer_crpinspection_archive 
            WHERE q_slno IN('15','17','19') 
            AND answer='YES'
            ) 
    AND q_slno='14';

Comment: what you want to do- can you please explain in your question

Comment: Hi Satish. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to review how to ask a good question: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Regards.

Comment: You want to set to `'YES'` something that is already to `'YES'` ? `SELECT * FROM adhoc_answer_crpinspection_archive WHERE q_slno IN('15','17','19') AND answer='YES'`

Comment: Why do you think you need a subselect? Why not add the `q_slno='14'` into the `IN()` **and what is the point in `AND answer='YES'` if you are trying to update `answer='YES'` ???? ?? ?? ????**

Comment: hii, i want if q_slno=15, 17 and 19 have answer='YES' then update q_slno=14th answer will YES

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using exists

```
UPDATE adhoc_answer_crpinspection_archive 
    SET answer='YES'
WHERE exists(
        SELECT 1 
        FROM adhoc_answer_crpinspection_archive 
        WHERE q_slno IN('15','17','19') 
        AND answer='YES'
        ) 
AND q_slno='14'
```

Comment: IMHO it should be `not exists` and `AND answer <> 'YES'`

Comment: `q_slno IN('15','17','19') ... AND q_slno='14'` will always be false